# purrr::possibly function possibly not working with map2_chr function

Tags: r, purrr

I suspect that this is a bug in the purrr package, but would like to check my logic in StackOverflow first, please.

It seems to me that the `possibly` function is not working inside the `map2_chr` function.  I'm using purrr version 0.2.5

Consider this example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

lets <- tibble(posn = 2:0,
               lets_list = list(letters[1:5], letters[1:5], letters[1:5])) %>% 
  glimpse()
```

returns

```
Observations: 3
Variables: 2
$ posn      <int> 2, 1, 0
$ lets_list <list> [<"a", "b", "c", "d", "e">, <"a", "b", "c", "d", "e">, <"a", "b", "c", "d", "e">]
```

In this example, I want to create another column using mutate to return the element in the list "lets_list" based on the value in "posn".

```
lets %>% 
  mutate(lets_sel = map2_chr(lets_list, posn, ~.x[.y]))
```

fails with this error message as the third row have posn = 0.

```
> lets %>% 
+   mutate(lets_sel = map2_chr(lets_list, posn, ~.x[.y]))
#    Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#      Evaluation error: Result 3 is not a length 1 atomic vector.
```

Using the `possibly` function with `map2_chr` returns an error too.

```
lets %>% 
  mutate(lets_sel = map2_chr(lets_list, posn, possibly(~.x[.y], NA_character_)))
# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#  Evaluation error: Result 3 is not a length 1 atomic vector.
```

However, the `map2` function works fine:

```
> lets %>% 
+   mutate(lets_sel = map2(lets_list, posn, possibly(~.x[.y], NA_character_)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   posn lets_list lets_sel 
  <int> <list>    <list>   
1     2 <chr [5]> <chr [1]>
2     1 <chr [5]> <chr [1]>
3     0 <chr [5]> <chr [0]>
```

A workaround solution is to use map2 and then map_chr, but I suspect that this is a bug.

```
> lets %>% 
+   mutate(lets_sel = map2(lets_list, posn, ~.x[.y]),
+          lets_sel = map_chr(lets_sel, possibly(~.x[1], NA_character_)))
    # A tibble: 3 x 3
       posn lets_list lets_sel
      <int> <list>    <chr>   
    1     2 <chr [5]> b       
    2     1 <chr [5]> a       
    3     0 <chr [5]> NA
```

Am I missing something here?
Thanks.

Comment: Just realised that in my workaround solution, possibly is not required inside the map2 function so I've changed the reproducable example.  My question still holds. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`possibly()` doesn't work because indexing with `0` doesn't throw an error;
it just returns a length 0 vector:

```r
nth_letter <- function(n) letters[n]

possibly(nth_letter, "not returned")(0)
#> character(0)

nth_letter(0)
#> character(0)
```

In this case it would probably be easier to replace invalid indices with `NA`
(using e.g. `dplyr::na_if()`, or plain old `ifelse` if the real problem is more complex) to get what you are after:

```r
lets %>% 
  mutate(lets_sel = map2_chr(lets_list, na_if(posn, 0), ~ .x[.y]))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    posn lets_list lets_sel
#>   <int> <list>    <chr>   
#> 1     2 <chr [5]> b       
#> 2     1 <chr [5]> a       
#> 3     0 <chr [5]> <NA>
```

Created on 2018-08-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Answer (score 1):

OK, now I'm thinking that this is just a "feature".  The most elegant solution / workaround is just:

```
lets %>% 
  mutate(lets_sel = map2(lets_list, posn, ~.x[.y]) %>% 
           map_chr(., possibly(~.x[1], NA_character_)))
```

Nowhere in the help screen suggests that safely and possibly can by used with the `map2` family of functions.  Hence I conclude that this is a "feature" rather than a "bug".
Thanks.